# How to change a Key in Object if Key value is number?

Tags: javascript

I'm new to javascript and have a question : i want to change *keys* if their *value* is *number* for example. What's wrong with my code?

```
const order = {
    wine : 100,
    vodka : 200,
    beer : 300,
    whisky : "not in stock"
};

function change(obj) {
    for (var prop in obj) {
        if (typeof obj[prop] === "number") {
            prop = "is number";
        }
    }
}

change(order);
console.log(order);
```

i want output to be

```
    is number : 100,
    is number : 200,
    is number: 300,
    whisky : "not in stock"
```

Comment: What are you expecting? What would be the output?

Comment: You aren't changing the object itself you're just creating a new local isntance in the function

Comment: @SajeebAhamed i eddited my question

Comment: @expressjs123 how can i edit it ? can you explain me please?

Comment: You can't have the same key multiple times in an object. They will just overwrite eachother

Comment: Object keys should be unique. So you cannot have an object with multiple `is number` keys, you can change the values though, but thats not what you are looking right?

Comment: You can add what is the reason for such a thing.

Comment: @kiranvj i just want to understand how to edit keys if their value is typeof something. trying to understand it and made this example to practice

Comment: @Reyno ah thank you

Comment: @SajeebAhamed i just want to understand how to change keys if i want it . no need to give them all same names, but want to understand how it works. how to call the key, if its value is typeof something

Comment: @SajeebAhamed yes thanks a lot

Comment: @MaxM we dont (cannot) edit keys, we add a new one and delete the old one .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change a key if it's value is a number, you need to clone the key and value first.
And then you need to delete the key in the object and once it's deleted it should be injected into the object again.

```
`function change(obj) {
    for (var prop in obj) {
        if (typeof obj[prop] === "number") {
            obj['is_number_' + obj[prop]] = obj[prop]
            delete obj[prop]
        }
    }
}`
```

The result should be like this :
is_number_100 : 100,
is_number_200 : 200,
is_number_300 : 300,
whisky : "not in stock"

Answer (score 0):

When you do this

> prop = "is number";

It is assigning "is number" to a variable called "prop". If you want to change the key, delete the existing key and create a new one.

Also, the keys are unique in an object. you cannot have multiple keys with same name.

```
function change(obj) {
    for (var prop in obj) {
        if (typeof obj[prop] === "number") {
            obj["is number"] = obj[prop];
            delete obj[prop];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The same key cannot exist in one object.

Comment: yes.. as the keys are unique, it will have only 1 "is number" key. And if he runs this in a loop, the "is number" will have 400
"is number"'s value will get overridden every time there is a number value.

Comment: Yes and OP doesn't want this. He is asking something invalid.